# AdMob real ads are not showing, only test ads are displayed

Tags: android, admob, banner

I have tested the ad feature on my phone. Only the test ad are show. When I replace the unit id with my which I got from AdMob, the real ads are not displayed.

What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
 <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-11*************1/7********5</string>
```

for xml i used

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

for loading ad i used

```
     AdView adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest= new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In manifeast I have

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

.
.
.

```
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

But my ads do not load in the android device. Test ads are working fine.
I used a real device for all of these operation. Any help please?

Comment: *For loading ad i used*, where is this code located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay the things are right as far as I see here. You donot necessarily need that templete way as mention above.

The ads are not showing because you may just have registered for ads. Your ad registeration should first be verified in google servers and that service should be activated and verified properly so that the request is not made from autoPrograms. So you should wait for at least 1-2 hours.
Regards.

Comment: omygod such simple answer but equal to diamonds. I nearly deactivated my playstore and admob account, Thnx mannnn

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `AdRequest`.

Change:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
```

to:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Google APIs for Android: [AdRequest.Builder setRequestAgent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder#setRequestAgent(java.lang.String))