# Admob Interstitial ad not loading - Android

Tags: android, admob

Test ads (with test ad id) are loading but the real ads are failed to load with error code id 1.

I checked that ad unit id is also right.

Every time its going to onAdFailedToLoad with value of i as 1

Please check the code

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        /*mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());*/
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(String.valueOf(R.string.admob_interstitial_ad_id));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        //.addTestDevice("25E662D1EDF4290XXXXXXXXXXXX")
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Log.e("TAG", "ADMOB INTERSTITIAL AD - " + i);
            }

            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it will take some time for ads to appear if you use real ids, if it's working with test ids. It means you have set it up correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob real ads are not showing, only test ads are displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374698/admob-real-ads-are-not-showing-only-test-ads-are-displayed)

Answer (score 0):

Test ads might be loading because the adUnitId is ignored but for production, your adUnitId doesn't appear to be correct. Look at this:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(String.valueOf(R.string.admob_interstitial_ad_id));
```

R.string.admob_interstitial_ad_id is an Integer that gets converted to string, but that's probably not what you are looking for. Try to get ad id as follows:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_ad_id));
```